# Why ed ≡ 1 (mod φ(n)) can be transfered to ed - 1 = kφ(n)?

Tags: algorithm, math, rsa

It is a step from RSA KEY generating operation. So many articles just say that ed ≡ 1 (mod φ(n)) equals ed - 1 = kφ(n).

I don't understand that how they change (mod φ(n)) to kφ(n) ?

Answer (score 5):

This  is by definition of congruence modulo N:

a ≡ b (mod N) is defined as "there exists an integer k such that a = b + kN"

Answer (score 0):

This response comes a bit late but maybe somebody else will research it in the future.

`ed ≡ 1 (mod φ(n))` This means that if you keep subtracting `φ(n)` from ed the last non-negative number you will get is 1. Therefore `1 + a multiple of φ(n) = ed` which you can also write as `ed = kφ(n)+1` with `k∈ℕ₀`. Subtract 1 on each side and you get `ed-1 = kφ(n)`